# How to fix background content shaking issue on desktop browser triggered by scrollbar toggle between those pages with diff page content height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

This issue occurs to me twice,

when using bootstrap 3 modal box, 
when modal box pops up, browser scroll bar appears in chrome desktop and it causes background content shake for about 0.5 sec to become static again. In mobile device however, as mobile browser desn't show scrollbar like windows chrome, people viewing in those browsers won't see this issue.

the valid hack I found for bootstrap modal issue is by applying css override like below:

```
.modal-open {
overflow: hidden;
width: calc(100% - 17px);/* for chrome/safari*/
width: -moz-calc(100% - 16px); /*for firefox*/
/*width: -ms-calc(100% - XXpx)  */
}
```

---

Now in jquery-mobile framework I also got this shaking problem when I click transitions from page to page , background image will shake after the page transition so it looks quite buggy if you view it in windows desktop browsers.

And I wonder if anyone has fix css for jquery mobile background shaking issue too appeared in desktop browser when data transition is fired between jquery-mobile pages of different page heights.

**senario example:**

page A : the page content is long so it has scrollbar when page fully loaded.

page B : the page content is short even when fully loaded there will be no scrollbar generated .

page C :  same with page A(content height has scrollbar);

page D :  same with page B(no scrollbar);

**triggers:** 
  using juqerymobile framework  link to
  trigger data-transition="***" between these pages:

**page A ->  page B  or page C -> page D** ,   shaking issue appears.

**page B -> page D** , shaking issue appears, as most transition still generates scrollbar in the progress, so you will see three status in between no scrollbar page transition:
   1.no-scrollbar  2.scrollbar visible or sliding  3.no-scrollbar

**page A -> page C**  ,   no shake as scroll bar all the way exists during the animation transition period.

Comment: actually this issue can be easily reproduced in jquery mobile transition demo page :http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html　after you close dialog transition back you'll see the content in the background shake in delay after the page transition is fully finished. (1st you see the page body without scrollbar, then when transition done, the scrollbar appears and you see a slight shaking effect in the background)

Answer (score 6):

Below is the solution I recently found and tested for removing the shaking effect caused by desktop browsers' show & hide effect of the scroll bar.
the solution seems very simple, works well for my project.

**Example fix code**

```
/* for chrome hidding scrollbar  */
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  width: 0px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very very much, It work for me very very well after many hard search. Nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I too had a webpage that experienced the shaking effect when the scrollbars would suddenly appear.  My solution is a little different.  My container has a width of 736px, so in the CSS for the body element I give it a much larger width of 1200px and indicated overflow-x:hidden. That seemed to work except it wasn't perfect.  So I indicated also a height of 1200px and overall overflow as hidden. The page now is impervious to any shaking.

Here's a link with [live code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxRdLQ), the critical part of which is as follows in the styling:

```
body {
  width:1200px;
  height:1200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#container {
  margin:auto;width:736px;
}
```

If you comment out the CSS for the body element, you'll then see the page shake again when the scrollbars appear.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the main body scrollbar flickering during some Bootstrap menu animation.  Similar to some other solutions here, I modified the body scrollbar behavior by having it always displayed:

```
body
{
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Fix Chrome jitter problem.*/
}
```